# PHP - REGEX TO ARRAY like MP3TAG

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I would like to ask how to convert a string to array using 
a string pattern like mp3tag does

%ALBUM% - %SOMETHING% - %SOMETHING%, 
the ' - ' are custom chars that are not static.

If i didnt made myself clear 
i want fro custom sting to make it an array
but the pattern is custom not static

Is this possible in php and if so how.

Comment: No. The chars inside are custom changing from user

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "%ALBUM% & %SOMETHING% (ノ゜-゜)ノ ︵ ┬──┬ %SOMETHING%,";
preg_match_all("/%([a-z]+)%/i", $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Outputs

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "%ALBUM%"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "%SOMETHING%"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "%SOMETHING%"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "ALBUM"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "SOMETHING"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "SOMETHING"
  }
}
```